# Displaying popular posts

Tags: query

I wanted to write a query to display, 3-4 top popular post, in my sidebar with a small thumbnail size image of the post. I tried looking at archives widget, but it only displayed links. (thought, i could copy the code from there), how do i get to have my desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach images to each post using "featured images" by first enabling  featured images for your theme using [add_theme_support('post-thumbnails')](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support), and [get_the_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) to display images.

For example, to list 4 most commented posts with their featured image and title, you can do something like this:

```
$posts = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 4,
        'order_by' => 'comment_count'
    )
);
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID)
    echo $post->post_title;
}
```

Read about [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more querying options. To get more advanced measurements, you may want to look into a plugin.

Comment: but its simple query, i want to display most popular posts and archive displays?

Comment: The example shows how to display post thumbnails with your posts, to get popular posts you have to add some criteria to the get_posts() call. You can for example order by comment count using `'orderby' => 'comment_count'`. It really depends on which measurement you use to determine if a post is popular

Comment: @stanlik now i have this http://pastebin.aquilenet.fr/?d133dd8ff1d9c11e#y7wq82HS7XJJavM+PmAVAcPfxbG271E180WIhP9eadw= and the date is just displaying for first post